# How to search string in string php?

Tags: php, string, function, text

I'm searching one PHP function or other solution for my problem.

So, I have a string, this:

```
$string = 'dfdfdjdkfjsdklfjdksfjekrjekjfdlkfjsdlfdflokuki48(malac)kjdkfdjfkjkejrkerjer';
```

I'm searching one function, that it has the next parameters:

```
functionName ($string, $fromCharacters, $toCharacters);
```

And I run this function:

```
functionName ($string, 'lokuki48(', ')');
```

And I will get this: `'malac',` or max. this: `'lokuki48(malac)'.`

Do you know about PHP function or solution for my problem?

I hope you understand my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: `strpos`, `substr` and tons of google results with `search string in string php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$string = 'dfdfdjdkfjsdklfjdksfjekrjekjfdlkfjsdlfdflokuki48(malac)kjdkfdjfkjkejrkerjer';
if (strpos($string, 'malac') !== false) 
{
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/SiPvO

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The **strstr()** function searches for the first occurrence of a string inside another string.

**Example**

Find the first occurrence of "world" inside "Hello world!" and return the rest of the string:

```
<?php
   echo strstr("Hello world!","world");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys!

I have found the solution:

```
`$string = 'dfdfdjdkfjsdklfjdksfjekrjekjfdlkfjsdlfdflokuki48(fasza)kjdkfdjfkjkejrkerjer';


function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
     $ini = strpos($string,$start);
     if ($ini == 0) return "";
     $ini += strlen($start);     
     $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
     return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

echo get_string_between($string,"lokuki48(",")");`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you love lókuki, use preg_match:

```
<?php

function search($string, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match("'".$start."(.*)".$end."'sim", $string, $out);

    if(isset($out[1])) {
        return $out[1];
    }

    return false;
}




$string = 'dfdfdjdkfjsdklfjdksfjekrjekjfdlkfjsdlfdflokuki48(malac)jdkfdjfkjkejrkerjer';

$start="lokuki48\(";
$end="\)";
$res = search($string, $start, $end);

echo $res."\n\n";




$string = 'dfdfdjdkfjsdklfjdksfjekrjekjfdlkfjsdlfdftestfunction(param1, param2)jdkfdjfkjkejrkerjer';

$start="testfunction\(";
$end="\)";
$res = search($string, $start, $end);

echo $res;
```